# Loop through resultset

Tags: java, jsp

UPDATE: I now need to get the string in a row form rather than in a column form.

How do you loop through a ResultSet (rs) using a for loop or a while loop in order to make the

```
<%
  <%=rs.getString(n)%>
%>
```

dynamically loop through all of the records in an SQL table?

This is possible with the following code but is "hard coded" and not dynamically created

```
<%
while(rs.next()){
%>

<%=rs.getString(1)%>

<%
}
%>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not the job of a JSP to loop over SQL queries. JSPs are glorified templates; use them for templating.

Comment: Not sure but a safe bet is to wrap the rs in a class implementing Iterable or Enumerable. I assume that JSP is expecting one of those interfaces for this functionality.

Comment: I now need to get the string in a row form rather than in a column form

Answer (score 1):

You can get total number of columns from MetaData and loop through it.

```
int numOfCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(rs.next()){
   for(int i=1;i<=numOfCols;i++){
        rs.getString(i); // Anything except blob can be retrieved as getString()
   }
}
```